# How can I map a JSON file directly into current instance?

Tags: c#, json, oop, json.net, this

I have a class with a number of members and I can create an instance directly by deserializing JSON into it using JSON.net.

How can I achieve the same result to the current instance of my class?

```
class Person {
    public string Name;
    public int Age;
    public string[] NickNames;

    public Person(){}

    public void LoadInfo(string textFile){
        Person p = this;
        p = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(textFile);

        // I want to do something like: this = p;
        // but I can't since this operator is read-only
    }
}
```

Comment: Just want to make sure, are you trying to map properties and values here from json to the class?

Comment: Can not assign <this> 'because it is read-only [ this=p is forbeden]

Comment: @KrishnaDhungana Yes, the json file stores the values of the properties, and I want them to be loaded to the current instance.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you aren't just using a constructor that takes JSON (or a static factory method)?

Comment: @lc. No, it's not even needed for this example. But for my actual code, it's used to instantiate it without loading the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you're searching for is JsonConvert.PopulateObject:

```
class Person {
    public string Name;
    public int Age;
    public string[] NickNames;

    public Person(){}

    public void LoadInfo(string textFile){
        JsonConvert.PopulateObject(textFile, this);
    }
}
```

Bottom line: if it's about Json, Json.Net does it!

Comment: I knew there would be such a method there! Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Don't add the `LoadInfo` method to the class you are trying to `deserialize`, create a separate wrapper class for this.

Then add the correct attributes.

Something like:

```
[DataContract]
public class Person {
    [DataMember]
    public string Name {get; set;}
    [DataMember]
    public int Age {get; set;}
    [DataMember]
    public string[] NickNames {get; set;}

    public Person(){}
}

public class PersonController
{
    public Person LoadInfo(string textFile){

        var p = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(textFile);

        //return an instance of person, mapped from the textfile.
        return p;
    }
}
```

If you want to keep it in the instance, you can do something like this using reflection:

```
 using System.Reflection;

 class Person {
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int Age  {get; set;}
    public string[] NickNames  {get; set;}

    public Person(){}

    public void LoadInfo(string textFile)
    {
            //assign the values to a new instance. 
            Person p = new Person();
            p = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person>(textFile);
            //get all the properties of the person class.
            var properties = this.GetType().GetProperties();
            //loop through the properties.
            foreach (var property in properties)
            {
                //Get the type (Person)
                Type type = this.GetType();
                //set the value for the property.
                type.GetProperty(property.Name).SetValue(this, type.GetProperty(property.Name).GetValue(p));
            }

     }
}
```

Comment: So basically the container class for JSON has to be a separate class on its own? I have thought about this approach, but I'd want to check if anyone knows a direct method. But this is still a valid answer.

Comment: I wouldn't know how you would map directly from within the class instance, you could I guess as part of `LoadInfo()` create a new instance of `Person` and then map the properties back to your current instance using `reflection`. But that seems a lot more complicated than having a wrapper.

Comment: Updated my answer using `reflection` to automatically map the properties back to the instance.

Comment: Keep it simple. JsonConvert.PopulateObject does exactly what the OP wants.

Comment: I can agree that the reflection can be a bit complex. The second code might not work as the class members are not properties type, they are fields type unless `{ get; set; }` for each member is defined as in the first snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You can not assign to `this` because it is a reference and it does not allow to reassign own reference. So if you want to map properties or create a new Person then I would like to suggest some options here:

1. Map properties manually

This means after you get the deserialised object, map new Person like:
this.Name = p.Name and so on..

2. Use Tools Like Automapper

Automapper is an object to object mapper. https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Getting-started

OR

Create a Wrapper Class like @JanR or use static method that creates the Person from the de-serialised object.

I hope this helps.